# Can I switch off built in laptop keyboard on boot up because it’s faulty

Tags: boot, keyboard

Some of my laptop’s keyboard keys are ‘acting as if pressed’ even though they’re not been pressed, and this is interfering with the boot up of Ubuntu. I have an external usb keyboard, so I want to switch off the internal keyboard before boot up, ie., before it gets the chance to cause boot up problems.

Can anyone help?

Quack

Comment: Problem solved....my internal keyboard is now disabled.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved....my internal keyboard is now disabled. First run

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Then find the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash"
```

and change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = “quiet splash i8042.nokbd”
```

Then save file and run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: seems worked. need to test